# AWK, filter lines which have two columns swapped

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with distances, these are 'A to B' and 'B to A'. I would like to filter out the 'B to A' line(s). I have tried many options, but am confused a bit about the awk syntax.

One thing I tried is a variant on this code

```
awk '!x[$1,$3]++'
```

I wanted to find a way to print the line and store the 'A' and 'B' an array of the reversed columns with

```
awk '{if (a[$1,$3]=!0) print $0} a[$3,$1]++'
```

or

```
awk 'a[$1,$3]==0 a[$3,$1]++'
```

The first one duplicates every line except the first one. The second prints no lines, is there maybe a delimiter needed between the arrays?

Comment: Provide us with sample input and output, that helps a lot.

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. Are `A` and `B` literal values in your input file? If not how should we know what's an A vs a B value? To become un-confused about awk syntax, read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: [Please see how to ask good questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, A and B are numbers like the example in the answer of karafka. His answer fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue

change field nums according to your data

```
$ cat dist
1       5
2       4
3       3
4       2
5       1

$ awk '($2,$1) in a{next} {a[$1,$2]; print}' dist
1       5
2       4
3       3
```

this can be also be written as

```
$ awk '($2,$1) in a{next} ++a[$1,$2]' dist
```

Comment: Another way `awk '!a[$1,$2]&&!a[$2,$1]++'`

Comment: How the heck are you figuring out what a "B to A" line vs "A to B" line is? When you see a line in a file that's "Chicago to Boston" and another that's "Boston to Chicago" - how can you tell whether Boston or Chicago is "A"?

Comment: first come first served...  It's a common problem to eliminate redundancies in a symmetric data if my assumptions are correct.  But you can never know until OP adds more details.

Comment: Thanks for providing the example, it works like a charm!

Comment: I intended A and B as numerical variables, so karafka gave the perfect example.